# wsdl2java generated code causes character encoding problems

Tags: maven, jetty, wsdl2java

I have generated a bunch of java-files from a WSDL source. I used Apache CXF 2.6.1 for generating the files.

When I put the code onto our production box that is running jetty and maven and I send a request to the server via the generated java-files it somehow changes the systems/JVM character encoding. The swedish characters å, ä and ö changes into Ã¥, Ã¤, Ã¶.

I can't reproduce this on my own box.

Someone have any idea?

Comment: This topic comes up in the CXF jira.

  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2450

Comment: Takes long but it's reachable.

Comment: Yes. It was reachable in Safari, but not in chrome.

Comment: The file.encoding=UTF-8 is already set. Any other ideas?

Comment: i had similar problems before; it was caused by http compression. perhaps you can check your web server config.

Comment: I "solved" my problem by writing my own SOAP client and skipping the generated one. Not the best solution, but I only used like 5 or 6 API calls, so I didn't need such a big client.

Answer (score 5):

Since version 2.5.4 there is a new command line option -encoding  which is not yet documented on the official [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html). But when you call the tool with the help option (-h|-help) you will see the encoding option:

```
wsdl2java ... -encoding UTF-8 ....
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no such option exists in the documentation in the provided link

Comment: 5 years later it is still not documented.