# maven wsdl2java produces wrong char while converting to lowercase package name

Tags: java, maven, character-encoding, lowercase, wsdl2java

i have a wsdl that contains classes named as like "InstantMessageSender".
I am using turkish q keyboard and windows while i am coding. When i tried to run "mvn wsdl2java" it produces
something like "com.example.ınstantmessagesender" instead of "com.example.instantmessagesender", after this i've changed keyboard language than i tried convert lowercase operation on notepad++ and it worked properly. but maven didnt. After i tried to change output and input encoding as utf-8,  i got same weird result.
this 'ı' character is turkish language specific but i dont want any turkish chars in generated class names or pakace names. how can i solve this.
thanks,

Comment: have you tried using the encoding option?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180231/wsdl2java-generated-code-causes-character-encoding-problems

Comment: yea, but it did not work. But i've find a solution; "changing the windows present language to english".